# gradle: api vs api project() difference

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, maven-3

I am quite new to gradle but have good experience with maven.
I am wondering what is the difference between these two below.

```
api project(':my-prj-1')
```

vs

```
api "com.mydomain:grpc-helper:${grpc-helperVersion}"
```

I can see that when using project, i am giving just the project name not the artifactory details.

So when should or when can i use `api project` and what is the difference compared with just `api`. And in this case is there any comparison possible with Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Sorry for my poor English)

I suppose you have a sub-project named `my-prj-1` that can build the sub-artifact `com.mydomain:grpc-helper`.

By `api project(':my-prj-1')`, when you build the main project, the sub-project will also get built and its artifact will be used in the main project. (1)

By `api "com.mydomain:grpc-helper:${grpc-helperVersion}"`, the main project will try to find the artifact from the repository only, if the sub-project is not built yet, the build will fail. (2)

From my experience, I would prefer the first approach since it a little bit safer. If the sub-artifact is already built then the sub-project build is skipped (due to incremental build) so there are no performance differences from the second approach.

Comment: fine.. that answers and you have explained it quite well. +1.

Comment: @Vamsh Since you say your question is answered, please accept the answer via the little checkmark icon next to it. Thanks!